# Переключение nav-tabs bootstrap при клике по ссылке

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap

На сайте есть раздел новостей, с двумя nav-tabs, они сейчас работаю корректно (переключаются между собой), но когда мы уже зашли в этот раздел, с уже одним активным табом, мы не можем переключить эти табы по прямой ссылке (в футере) на другой 
Пример кода:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs news-btn-container">
            <li role="presentation" class="">
                <a href="#auto-news" aria-controls="auto-news" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">
                    АВТО-новости</a>
            </li>
            <li role="presentation" class="active">
                <a href="#market-news" aria-controls="market-news" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="true">
                    Новости рынков                   </a>
            </li>
                </ul>
```

и сам футер

```
<div class="col-md-2">
            <p class="fm-title">Новости</p>
            <p class="fm-point">
                <a href="/ua/news#market-news">Новости рынков</a>
            </p>
            <p class="fm-point">
                <a href="/ua/news#auto-news">Авто-новости</a>
            </p>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот что в итоге получилось, может кому то пригодятся)

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var url = window.location.toString();           
        if (url.match('#')) {               
            $('.nav-tabs a[href="#' + url.split('#')[1] + '-tab"]').tab('show');                 
        }
        $('.fm-point a').on('click', function (e) {
              $('.nav-tabs a[href="'+  e.target.hash +'"]').tab('show');
        });
    });
```